# How to refresh a table? Java(not tablemodel, JTable table)

Tags: java, refresh, panel

```
            Object[][] productData = {{"","","",""}};

            JTable table = new JTable(productData, productHeadings);    
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            panel.add(scrollPane);

            scrollPane.setSize(590,335);
            scrollPane.setLocation(345,60);
            panel.add(scrollPane);

            panel.validate();
            table.validate();
            scrollPane.validate();
            (new BuyProduct()).validate();
            panel.repaint();
            table.repaint();
            scrollPane.repaint();
            (new BuyProduct()).repaint();
```

How can i refresh my table?(i am not using table model, just a simple table), this code is put inside of a action listener, (the listener works fine), just ym problem is that i can not get the table refreshed.

Comment: Why aren't you using a tableModel if I may ask? I do not see why you want to refresh it here. The table values does not change apparently.

Comment: You are using a `TableModel`, the `JTable` converts `productData` to a `TableModel` internally.  You need to use the resulting model in order to influance the `JTable`, this is common requirement of the MVC implementation of Swing

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Since you appear to be using `null` layouts, it's pointless calling `validate`, as this is related to getting the layout managers to update their layouts

Comment: A `JTable` will display the contents of it's `TableModel`, it will also respond to changes within the model and update it's view.  You can't use a `JTable` without some kind of model been involved, this is simply how the API works

Comment: I think it is more simple for me to do it with a simlpe table, because I am using a table which i am not planning to change a lot, i am not going to input any data in it by myself, the table chagnes by it self, i do not do any inputs for it, I just want to resfresh it depending on the if statetement. @YassinHajaj

Comment: Is there any way to change the table on the way it is now? without a need to make ita  tablemodel

Comment: @Franko I used to do it by deleting the old table and displaying the new one. But using tableModel explicitely is way more efficient I think.

Comment: @Franko No. You're missing the point. You can't use a `JTable` without a `TableModel`, it's simply not possible, even the `JTable` converts your `productData` and `productHeadings` into a `TableModel` internally.  If you want to replace what's there, then simply create a new `TableModel` and assign it to the `JTable`, this will cause the `JTable` to be updated with the new data

Comment: @MadProgrammer If so, can you explain me how to use the table model to implement it for refreshing the table? Many thanks

Comment: @franko [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). The answer will depend on what you mean by refreshing. You could, for example, build a new `TableModel` and use `JTable#setModel` which will completely update the table with the new data; you could use `DefaultTableModel` and use it's `setRowCount` passing it `0` to remove all the preexisting rows and use `addRow` to add new rows

Comment: @MadProgrammer it is a very simple change, no adding rows, or other stuff, for example
if(something)
{
Object[][] productData = {{"","","",""}};
}
else
{
Object[][] productData = {{"DataExample","DataExample,"DataExample","DataExample"}};
}

Comment: `table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{{"","","",""}}, productHeadings));`, although `model.setRowCount(0);` and `model.addRow(new Object[]{"","","",""});` (assuming `model` is an instance of `DefaultTableModel`) would be more efficent